# How to add user for Jetty 7 in windows OS

Tags: linux, windows, solr, jetty

I am learning how to use Jetty 7 for the first time.
I followed the steps in this tutorial:
https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrJetty

The website is presenting the steps using Linux command (I believe). However I am using windows 7, and I am stuck at the Create User portion.

```
Creating user

Don't forget to create solr user in the system.

useradd -d /opt/solr -s /sbin/false solr
chown solr:solr -R /opt/solr
chown solr:solr -R /var/log/solr # if you use alternative folder for logs
NOTE: If you don't have start-stop-daemon tool you have to setup /bin/bash instead /sbin/false.
```

So my question is how do I do this in Windows?

Answer (score 0):

a very good way is to use [yajsw](http://yajsw.sourceforge.net/). This will allow you to install Solr as a service in windows, and also in unix/linux, as it is cross platform. So if you learn how to use it in one OS it will be very similar in others.

I have used it many times in linux/windows.